# Conventional commits when to use Fix vs Feat

Tags: git, conventional-commits

So according to conventional commits fix is used to patch a bug in the codebase while feat  introduces a new feature to the codebase, which is straightforward enough.

What if I have a commit that is something that's not really a bug but not a feature either? In my case its a commit that's changing some text on a webpage. This doesn't seem like it qualifies as a "feature" but its also not exactly a bug either

Comment: Sounds like a feature to me. Some workplaces would call this a task.

Comment: You could define more labels besides Fix and Feat.

Comment: The second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74997821/184546) gives some examples of additional labels you can use, including making up your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not a `fix` because you're fixing a bad text that have been introduced early, for me it's `feat` because you are doing an improvement to your website. Not one with huge added value but one with it still...

You have also other keywords generally used in [conventional commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/#summary) and if you juge that your change is not important enough to use `feat`, maybe you could use `chore`.